# How to make Flow and Typescript work together in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flowtype, react-typescript

So, how to make Flow and Typescript work together in React? You will ask why you have both in the same project, but I am in the middle of the transition from Flow to Typescript, and for a brief period of time I would like to have them both.

The problem is, Flow reports an error for Typescript type definitions like this:

```
type person = {
 name: string
 surname: string
}
```

because Flow syntax is different:

```
type person = {
 name: string,
 surname: string,
}
```

I am using the VS Code and I can not find where (and how) to disable Flow to mark Typescript syntax as faulty and fail the compilation process. I tried everything: // @noflow, // $FlowFixMe but nothing can prevent reporting error on Typescript syntax.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why not just add the commas for now? TS will accept them.

Comment: Well, no. Typescript linter automatically delete commas.

Comment: That's some other tool in your build chain, not TypeScript

Comment: Yes I agree, but I don't know which other tool is in question.

Comment: Ok, I found it... Check out my other post.

Comment: Btw, is Flow so bad? I constantly hear that Flow team makes some improvements.

Comment: It is not so bad, but Typescript is defacto industry standard, and to be compatible with all others I must switch to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. In my case, I needed two lines on the top of the file:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/* eslint-disable flowtype/no-types-missing-file-annotation */
```

This will do the trick.